# Predict probabilities of a recommender system?

Tags: sparse-matrix, recommendation-engine, svd

I have a dataset where I have a sparse utility matrix (user-product) with binary input: 1 if the user  bought the product , and 0 if it hasn't.

However it has a different meaning on the test set, 0 means that we don't know if the user bought this product, and 1 means that we're sure that the user bought that given product.

I need to get for each user in each product the probability that a user  bought a product  in the test set. For this I wish to use different matrix factorization techniques like FunkSVD, NMF or SVD++ , but I'm quite confused:

These techniques would only allow me to get the label (1 or 0) on test set, but I need to compute a probability of getting 1 and not the label in it self.

How can I approach this problem ? Or do I treat it as a classification problem and then use all common classification techniques ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, One approach that might help based on [Recurrent-Knowledge-Graph-Embedding](https://github.com/sunzhuntu/Recurrent-Knowledge-Graph-Embedding).

Try converting user-item interactions into a knowledge graph and mine the `top-n` paths in the graph between `user_i` and `item_j`. Build an RNN model as described in the paper and its code, to get probabilities.